# Jquery Datepicker weekends only between certain dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to get datepicker to show only weekends available between two specific dates.  The code I have will show only weekends, or it will only show available between the dates, but not the expected result.  Here's what I've got right now:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    "dateFormat": 'yy/mm/dd',
    'minDate': new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      if (dt.getMonth() > 3 && dt.getMonth() < 8) {
        return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
      } else {
        return [true, "", "Available"];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

This shows only the weekends available, but now I need to limit that to weekends only between May 27th and August 17th and everything available after August 17th.  Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: The code you have already limits the month. This is 99% of the way. What exactly is the trouble with also limiting the day?

Comment: @Tomalak, if you run the code snippet, it's doing the block for the entire month of May and the entire month of August.  We need weekdays to be available before May 27th and after August 17th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another nested if section to define dates within months. if you wanna include the dates, just make it `<=` or `>=` instead of just `<` and `>`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    "dateFormat": 'yy/mm/dd',
    'minDate': new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      if (dt.getMonth() > 3 && dt.getMonth() < 8) {        
        if (dt.getMonth() == 4 && dt.getDate() < 26) {
          return [true, "", "Available"];
        }
        if (dt.getMonth() == 7 && dt.getDate() > 17) {
          return [true, "", "Available"];
        } 
        return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
      } 
      else {
        return [true, "", "Available"];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!